# "Missing required key 'Key' in params" in Get operation of Dynamo dB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing Lambda function in node.js to getitems from dynamodB. Table is employee where emo_Id is the Partition key. Below is the code snippet I am writing:

```
var table = "Employee_Test";
var emp_Id=event.emp_Id;
var emp_Name=event.emp_Name;
var params = {
TableName: table,
    KeyConditionExpression: "#eId = :Id",
        ExpressionAttributeNames:{
            "#eId": "emp_Id"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":Id":emp_Id
        }}
```

The error I am getting is :
  "message": "Missing required key 'Key' in params",
  "code": "MissingRequiredParameter",

I know the resolution of the error is to add:
 Key:{
        "emp_Id": emp_Id,
} to the code. But If I have to query the employees who have joined after a particular date then I cannot provide emp_Id as a parameter.

In the AWS release notes I have found that we can disable parameter validation,
https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/6967335344676381  I tried this but this is also not working.

Can somebody please help?

Thanks
Shweta

Comment: Did you try to set the parameter validation to false at global level (or) at your service level?

Comment: Can you also post your `aws.config` here?

Comment: @DavidR Hi David, This is the configuration:

 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 var dynamoDBConfiguration = {
    "accessKeyId": "",
 "secretAccessKey": "",
    "region": "us-west-2"
  };
AWS.config.update(dynamoDBConfiguration);
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
var dynamodb1 = new AWS.dynamodb({ paramValidation: false });

Comment: As per the blog, it is for S3 bucket. I dont think that feature is applicable for DynamoDB

Comment: @shwetadixit Had you tried setting the `paramValidation:false` globally?. Something like, `AWS.config.paramValidation = false;` ?

Answer (score 20):

I was hit with a same error when querying the secondary indexes. Turns out that I was using the wrong API. Confused between getItem and Query.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this when I first started with DynamoDb.  Such an annoying error.  Turns out I had accidentally used the `.get` method, from a previous working `getById` example, instead of the `.query` method.

In short, you may just need to change *this* ...

`const response = await db.get(query).promise();`

... to this ...

`const response = await db.query(query).promise();`

Comment: I can't believe i didn't noticed that on my code too! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a Global Secondary Index to your table to enable lookups by start date. First, change your item creation code (PutItem) to add an attribute representing the month and year an employee joined, like joinYearMonth=201612. Second, scan your table to find items that do not already have this attribute and add it. Third, create a Global Secondary Index with a partition key of joinYearMonth and a sort key of joinTimestamp. This way, you can issue query requests on the GSI for the years and months you require to find those that joined.